# Is R shiny secure by doing so?

Tags: r, security, shiny

I want to create a Shiny app that could share within my company. Though my company laptop don't allow the *Shinyapps.io*, I used my personal laptop to successfully run a shiny test.

My question is, is there any potential security issue if I use my personal laptop to run the company data using shiny, and share the output to my coworkers.

If the security is violated by doing so, what are other options to make it secure only to the company?

Answer (score 1):

Anything hosted on shiny server will be available to anyone who is able to connect to your laptop. If you want to work around this, you can use NGINX and require people to authenticate on another page before they can gain access to shiny, which you host locally and connect through a websocket. However, you're likely to mess up on some security thing (because it's incredibly easy to get security wrong), and people will gain access to either the raw data (which is extremely terrifying) or whatever visualizations you create in shiny (which is still terrifying). If you just use runApp("my-app"), and then screenshot visualizations from your computer to send around, you're fine, but if the data goes anywhere on the internet, I wouldn't consider it safe.

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback off of @ConCave on the issues of data privacy - the main issue of sharing your Shiny apps over shinyapps.io is that the data will need to be hosted on those external servers. If your company happens to have an IT support system that can recreate/host the entire Shiny server on their own servers, you could port your apps onto their server.